# Price Predition for Irregular spaced historic data of non independent Prices

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, forecasting

I am a little unsure how to proceed. I am not an expert but on a decent intermediate level when it comes to regular Timeseries.

Now i am faced with a problem that first seemed related, but is an entirey different Topic as it seems. I need a few pointers where to start.

I want to estmiate future prices of a specific Product. This Product is manufactured by many different Companies. I a decent chunk of historic data for all of these manufactures. The historic data is not evently spaced at all.

- Since a new Price point refelcts a well-considered decision off lets say a Pricing Manager to set a price at this specific point in time, i do not want to simply resample the data
- The relative movement of the Prices refelects the fact that there is actual competition between theses Products and Prices have a relation

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to predict for all manufacturers or for only one of these?

Comment: Preferable i would like to predict the whole ensemble.... But for a start i would like to have a pointer on how to predict a single manufacturer. Potentially, the relative movement of the prices indicates who is leading the market and who is not.
A simple regression modell fails miserably. I works however quite decently if i build aggregates of the market.

Comment: For an economist point of view predicting for single manufacturer is fairly complicated because of competition. Ideally this needs to be modeled in a 'Game' framework to model the internal dynamics of competition. For the overall picture though, you can take the average price across manufacturers and model that. As for the problem of irregular observations, you can either use state-space approach or fill the missing observations using some imputation method.

Comment: With Game Framework, you mean game Theory? Would you have a few search terms for me to get startet? Is there really no ML alogrithm, that could use one price as predictor and the other prices/date combinations as features? Lets for example asume product B is always priced withon 5% of Product A wich is the Leader in this marked. Are there algorithms that can detect this?

Comment: Yes I did mean game theory but, as I said, that is one of the methods. It will be, perhaps, best in theory. ML techniques can also work great for prediction. Let me put it this way: $P_t^b = f(P_{t-1}^b, P_{t}^a, \dots )$. Objective is to *discover* $f(.)$. Using game framework you can *derive* this function and then estimate it statistically. In ML techniques, the exact form of $f(.)$ is not required (it is hidden somewhere in the internal calculations) but direct outputs can be predicted.